Shared Memory Provider: No process is on the other end of the pipe. Unable to open a logical session
During the normal use of my program, I received the following error message:
"Shared Memory Provider: No process is on the other end of the pipe. **Unable to open a logical session**"

After getting this error I noticed that my program was unable to read the data from the SQL tables.
The only thing that helped was recovering some of my DB tables again
My question is: What does this SQL error mean? What does "Unable to open logical session" mean? What could be the reason this started happening (It worked great for years with no problem)?

Does this answer your question? Error message: (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

Hi. No. i don't think it's exactly the same issue. I was wondering what "Unable to open a logical session" means

Hi - what’s the program you’re referring to? What was the program doing when you got this error? What does this have to do with SQL (it’s not obvious from your question)? Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using

The program read data from the SQL Server and do some manipulation on it. The program was running when this error occured.

You're looking at the wrong part of the message. You are "unable to open a logical session" because there is "no process on the other end of the pipe". It's the "no process" part you should be worried about. But also, you should be worried you are using a DB that has been fully end of life for nearly 2 years now, meaning it's hasn't had a security update in a long time, such that it's unsafe and irresponsible to continue using it.

Thank you, Joel. So, does error means communication error with the SQL Server?

As it’s the program that’s giving the error, providing some information about the program might be helpful
